# Getting error Unrecognized sentinel configuration statement

Tags: redis

I have created sentinel File as per below: sentinel.conf

sentinel monitor myHAsetup 10.147.55.132 6379 1
sentinel down-after-mlliseconds myHAsetup 6001
sentinel failover-timeout myHAsetup 60000
sentinel parallel-syncs myHAsetup 1
bind 10.147.55.132

While running it, getting below error
[root@harish bin]# ./redis-server /etc/redis/sentinel.conf --sentinel

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 2

> > > 'sentinel down-after-mlliseconds myHAsetup 6001'
> > >       Unrecognized sentinel configuration statement.